# how to see the values I send with the in-app event to Appsflyer?

Tags: android, ios, events, mobile, appsflyer

I used the this tutorial to capture logEvent and then send data to AppysFlyer as in-app events.

I can find the event in the dashboard, for example, how many logins, signup, purchase, etc. but I couldn't find the actually values I sent there.

[image]

I couldn't find the top_up_amount and top_up_method in the dashboard of Appsflyer, but I do see an event about wallet_complete_topup.

anyone know where can I get such Parameter value? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure that out?